# Code standards for block formatting

Tags: php, if-statement, formatting, code-organization

There are two primary ways to format blocks of code.

I'm used to doing stuff like so:

```
function do_something() {
    if(cond) {
        if (cond 2) {
            if (cond 3) {
                whatever_good();
            } else
                whatever_bad3();
        } else
            whatever_bad2();
    } else
        whatever_bad1();
}
```

But recently I was introduced to this type of organising code:

```
function do_something() {
    if(!cond) {
        whatever_bad1();
        return;
    }
    if (!cond 2) {
        whatever_bad2();
        return;
    }
    if (!cond 3) {
        whatever_bad3();
        return;
    }

    whatever_good();
}
```

This second way is more readable, I have to admin. But it just makes me cringe to write code like that... Even tho I realise that the second if probably better. I think I just have to change my habits.

So. My question is: Is there some guidelines on how to structure code in a better way? This may be too broad, but this is something that you can't find easily in google. Especially this particular case for these two ways of writing code. I tried to find comparison of these two ways, but couldn't find even a single article about it. Also maybe some guidelines on improving readability.

So, I would really appreciate some links.

PS - Right now I'm asking this for php, but I think this also works for most other languages. So, this does not have to be necesary sticktly about php.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
if(cond1 && cond2 && cond 3) {
    something_good();
}
else {
    something_bad();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this not exactly an actualy code as you should understand :) The could could contain many different conditions and else statements with different returns (error codes for example) and maybe single "good" return, so you can't format it as you just did. But I'm not really asking for how to format the code in my questions. I'm asking for some articles with guidelines on organising your code for better readability and possibly performance.

Comment: In that case you should change your code to `something_bad1()` `something_bad2()` `something_bad3()` to indicate different code. Also, this might be more appropriate on Programmers since Stackoverflow is explicitely for decisive answers and not for debatable questions.

Comment: Okay, I will do that. As for "more appropriate on Programmers" I think you are right... I should have probably asked it there...